# Realtek r8168 Internet connection continuously failing

Tags: realtek

Using Arch Linux derived os. My computer connects to the internet on start-up but after a random amount of time the internet connection fails. And you have to reconnect. Using Realtek r8168 Ethernet Card with r8168 drivers. How to fix this issue.

[image]

Comment: Check `dmesg` output

Comment: Hear is the part related to the R8168 from dmesg --kernel. [    4.063930] r8168: This product is covered by one or more of the following patents: US6,570,884, US6,115,776, and US6,327,625.
[    4.065966] r8168  Copyright (C) 2020  Realtek NIC software team <nicfae@realtek.com>

Comment: Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: It's unlikely you're getting this little output from your driver.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have opensource driver "r8169" package. Install "r8168-dkms" driver. It's proprietary.